# Gnome screenshot: turn off camera sound *without* admin rights

Tags: gnome, audio, screenshot

Is there a way to disable the gnome screenshot camera sound, with needed admin access?  There's an answer here, that involves moving a file from somewhere in /usr/...

[How can I disable the shutter sound of gnome-screenshot?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93368/how-can-i-disable-the-shutter-sound-of-gnome-screenshot)

I don't have enough privileges to do that on my system.  Is there another way?

Thanks.

Comment: A new answer has been added to the linked question, explaining how to do it without admin rights.